# What will this function return? An empty Array or Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

```
var rowData = [];

function someName() {
    JsonClient.onload = function () {
        rowData.push("sasas");
        rowData.push("sasas1");
        rowData.push("sasas2");
        rowData.push("sasas3");
    };

    return rowData;
}
```

This returns me an empty rowData. Why?

**Guys it was an typo mistake by me while posting**

Comment: You have syntax errors in each "push" line

Comment: Well I guess, the rowData is not in the scope of your someName() function, Bcoz it is declared inside the other function.....?

Comment: Why don't you just test it yourself :D

Comment: check your code, you have errors on the strings, you forgot to close "

Comment: Make sure your code is valid, check the error console, also make sure the functions are called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `someName` is never called (e.g. `someName();`). Since it is never called, the `push` statements are never executed.

Even if it were called, the `someName` function just assigns an anonymous callback function to `JsonClient.onload`. Your code doesn't show us what `JsonClient` is, but it seems to be a safe assumption that it is an event handler for an HTTP Response. That function won't be called until the HTTP Response is received by the browser, by which time the `return` statement would already have been executed. **You can't return from an Ajax request, you have to deal with the data in the callback itself**.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function that declares an anonymous function that will not execute until your JsonClient has loaded.

You will need to do this:

```
var rowData = [];
function someName(){
   JsonClient.onload = function(){
     rowData.push("sasas");
     rowData.push("sasas1");
     rowData.push("sasas2");
     rowData.push("sasas3");
     useRowData(rowData);
   };
   // here I would expect a call like JsonClient.send();
}
function useRowData(rowData) {
  alert(rowData);
}
someName(); // execute the actual function
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close quotes on each string you're trying to push.. Once you do that it will return an array of strings.

Comment: No... it was the not the problem... why my rowData is empty

Answer (score 0):

You didn't closed strings... this should work
 var rowData = [];

```
function someName(){
   JsonClient.onload = function(){
   rowData.push("sasas");
   rowData.push("sasas1");
   rowData.push("sasas2");
   rowData.push("sasas3");
};

return rowData;
```

}